# Torsion in profinite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-algebras, profinite-groups, p-groups

Is there a finitely generated profinite group $G$ with a closed subgroup of infinite index $K \leq G$ such that for every $g \in G$ there exists some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $g^n \in K$ ?

Can $G$ be pro-$p$, for some prime number $p$?

Comment: Do you want to exclude groups like $\mathbb{Z}/2^\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @HenrikRüping I am not sure which group are you talking about, but if it is $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^\mathbb{N}$ then it is excluded since I am asking about finitely generated groups.

Comment: No, if you assume that there is a bound on the $n$'s, or if $K$ is normal.  I think the first is equivalent to the positive solution of the Restriceted Burnside Problem; the second follows from Zelmanov's Lie algebra analogue of Shirshov's theorem for associative algebras.

Comment: @YassineGuerboussa How do you solve the case of bounded $n$ with the burnside problem if $K$ is not normal?

Comment: Wouldn't the profinite completion of an infinite, residually finite, finitely-generated p-group (e.g. Grigorchuk's group) have this property?  The subgroup $K$ would be the trivial subgroup.

Comment: Grigorchuk's group is a p-group, but its profinite completion is not.  As far as I know, it is still an open question as to whether there exists a profinite group with infinite exponent, but no elements of infinite order.

Comment: @JimBelk it is known that $K$ can't be taken to be normal. By Zelmanov's solution of the Burnside problem, every finitely generated torsion profinite group is finite.

Comment: @Pablo: If there is a bound on the n's, we may assume that $x^n\in K$, for some $n$ and for all $x$.  The subgroup $G^n$ generated by all the $x^n$'s lies in $K$, and so is $\overline{G^n}$.  We have only to show that $G/\overline{G^n}$ is finite. First, note that $\overline{G^n}$ is the intersection of open normal subgroups containing it.  By the solution of RBP, there is a bound $f(d,n)$ on the orders of $d$-generated finite $p$-groups satisfying the identity $x^n$.  If we assume that $G$ is $d$-generated, then $|G/N|$ is bounded by $f(d,n)$, for every normal open subgroup $N$

Comment: -containing $\overline{G^n}$.  Pick such a $N$ such that $G/N$ has the maximal possible order.  If $M$ is another normal open subgroup containing $\overline{G^n}$, then so is $M\cap N$, if $N$ does not lie in $M$, then $G/(M\cap N)$ has order greater than $|G/N|$, a contradiction.  Thus $N$ is contained in every normal open subgroup containing $\overline{G^n}$; so $N=\overline{G^n}$.

Comment: You have mentioned that Zelmanov's solution of RBP, implies  that every finitely generated torsion profinite group is finite.  I'm not sure about this; it is more safe to say that it implies that  every finitely generated  profinite group of finite exponent is finite.  The result that you mentioned follows from a more general result of Zelmanov (which I'm not sure that is equivalent to the positive solution of the RBP).

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment.

I note first that I made an attempt to reduce the problem to the case where $K$ is normal, but it turned out to be false; I'm thankful to Ian Agol for his discussion.  The case where $K$ is normal follows at once from a theorem of Zelmanov stating that every periodic torsion group is locally finite.

This second attempt is not a complete answer; however, it reduces the problem considerably:

*Let $G$ be as above, then, virtiually, $L_p(G)$ satisfies a PI, for every prime $p$; with $L_p(G)$ denotes  the Lie algebra associated to the dimension subgroups (over the field of $p$ elements).*

Indeed, let $K_n$ denote the set of elements of $G$ satisfying $x^n\in K$.  As $K$ is closed, each $K_n$ is closed.  By assumption, $\cup_{n\geq1} K_n=G$, so by the standard Baire category theorem, there exists $n$ such that $K_n$ contains an open subset, so there is an open normal subgroup $N$ and $t\in G$ such that $tN \subseteq K_n$.

Let $H=\langle t \rangle N$, then $H$ is open.  Consider the subgroup generated by $X$, the set of the elements $(tx)^n$, with $x\in N$.  Then $X$ is a normal subset of $M$, and $X \subseteq K$ by the above paragraph.  It follows that the closed subgroup $L$ generated by $X$ lies $K$.

Let us work now in the finitely generated profinite group $M/L$ ($K$ may be identified with $K/L$.  We have $M/L$ satisfies the coset identity $X^n=1$ with respect to $N/L$ (see Wilson and Zelmanov's http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404992901386), by the main result in the previous paper, the Lie algebra $L_p(M/L)$ satisfies a polynomial identity.  This proves the claim.

**Remark.** If $G$ is a pro-$p$ group, then we can find a finite generating set of $M/L$ in which every element satisfies the identity $X^n=1$ (take $t$ together with $tx_1,..,tx_s$, where $x_1,..,x_s$ generate $N$; or actually thier images in $M/L$).  I wished to deduce from this (using the remark by Professor Yiftach Barnea in his answer [Elements of infinite order in a profinite group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455/elements-of-infinite-order-in-a-profinite-group)) that $M/L$ is finite, from which it follows that $K$ has a finite index in $G$.  Unfortunately, it seems that this remark is incorrect.

Comment: Maybe you can expand the argument in your fourth sentence - I don't understand why one has only finitely many conjugates to intersect in the identity.

Comment: Ok, in a compact space, from every family of closed subsets which intersect trivially, one can extract a finite subfamily which intersects trivially. (Please check if I done a mistake in the answer; usually, this is the case)

Comment: By intersect trivial, you mean intersect in the identity element? I don't see why this follows from point-set topology.

Comment: As usual, I done a stupid mistake. I'm using trivially to mean "empty".  The answer is false.  I have to delete it.